I am not able to see trace attached to component while dragging component in Altium
While dragging the component in Altium, I cannot see a trace attached to the component.
I checked all the settings, I even reset all settings but it is still not working.
Can anyone help me?
I want something like below image while dragging:


Go in the schematic a double check that there is connection from this component. Try and move the component and see if the net follows.

TRIED NOT WORKING

Could you also show your schematic?

Sure, But I think there is something wrong with the setting I have Altium installed on the desktop, and my laptop on my laptop I'm able to drag the component with the track but on my desktop, it's not showing

Yes I see. It is not the first time with Altium. I have found that a reset of preferences is necessary sometimes.

I have figured out how to enable track while dragging component must press N while dragging component and this should work
